# How to use insertBefore and appendChild with a jQuery AJAX server side rendered html result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, appendchild, prepend

I basically need to use insertBefore and appendChild with a Server Side rendered HTML page jQuery AJAX result. I get the error: "Failed to execute 'inserBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

```
var parent_elem = $('#parent_elem');
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'example.com/my_ajax_call',
    data: {"my_data":my_data},
    success:function(data){
        parent_elem.prepend(data); //THIS IS THE JQUERY SOLUTION BUT I NEED PURE JS WHILE USING JQUERY AJAX REQUEST
    },
    fail:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('failed to load page');
    }
});
```

what I am trying to do is this:

```
var parent_elem = document.getElementById('parent_elem');
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'example.com/my_ajax_call',
    data: {"my_data":my_data},
    success:function(data){
        parent_elem.inserBefore(data, parent_elem.firstChild); //THIS IS WHAT I NEED BUT IT THROWS ERROR "Failed to execute 'inserBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."
    },
    fail:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('failed to load page');
    }
});
```

Comment: So where is parent_elem defined and what is it supposed to be pointing at? Show HTML etc

Comment: hello, I edited my question, the parent element is a pure javascript selected DOM element var parent_elem = document.getElementById('parent_elem');

Comment: `data`  is not a node [See the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: yes that is what the error says, is there a way to make it work? how can I convert it to a node? I really am keen on using the pure js insertBefore compared to prepend as much as possible

Comment: add `dataType: "html"` to your ajax request

Comment: still the same error @vanowm

Comment: then check what `data` is: `console.log(data);`

Comment: It is an entire html page sent from the server

Comment: The type, check the type, string, object, etc

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to do that, all I am seeing on the response is the html, not an object, not an array, not a string. The actual html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn HTML string into a node you can use jQuery function around it:

`var node = $("<h1>hello world</h1>")`

So in your case:

```
parent_elem.inserBefore($(data)[0], parent_elem.firstChild);
```

Comment: It's not gonna work this way, because `$(data)` will create jquery object, not an HTML element which required by `insertBefore()`

Comment: Correct, I fixed it. Also this assumes only 1 node in the resulting html data. Otherwise you can always <div> pad around it.

Comment: I am still getting the same error :( EDIT: IT WORKED WITH THE [0] !!!!! THANK YOUUU!

Comment: While we're at it, may I ask about your opinion about which method is faster and more efficient? the pure jQuery solution or this one?

Comment: Your welcome. You could use vanilla JS for this but it is negligible comparing to the ajax call itself (which uses jQuery anyway)

Comment: Do you mean pure Javascript or this one? jQuery is a bloatware and should be avoided if perfrormance needed. This is why we need hardware upgrades, to keep up with software which become slower and slower because developers become lazzy and rather go after convinience of packages like jQuery, rather than be performance conscience